# UpsertResult isCreated is not working

Tags: apex, soql, upsert

I am having issues with Upserting data. Here is my code:

```
global static void MyMethod(string param1, string objName, string param2) {

    CustomObject__c record = new CustomObject__c();
    record.Param1__c = param1;          
    record.Name = objName; 
    record.Param2__c = param2;
    record.User__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
    record.UpsertField__c = param1 + '_' + UserInfo.getUserId();
    //upsert record UpsertField__c;

    List<CustomObject__c> myRecords = new List<CustomObject__c>();
    myRecords.add(record);

    Schema.SObjectField f = CustomObject__c.UpsertField__c;
    Database.UpsertResult[] urList = Database.upsert(myRecords, f);
    for (Database.UpsertResult ur : urList) {
        if (ur.isCreated) {
            //set counter to 1 on custom object, something like:
            record.Counter__c = 1;
        } else {
            //increment counter by 1
            record.Counter__c++;
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: isCreated at line 25
>   column 20

My understaing is that 'isCreated' is part of UpsertResult class. Please help me what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isCreated` is a method that returns a boolean value, not a boolean property. As such this is what you want to do

```
ur.isCreated()
```

[UpsertResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_upsertresult.htm)

Additionally, this will fail as well `ur.Counter__c = 1;` as there are no custom fields possible on UpsertResult

Comment: I meant it was record.Counter__c. So is there a way to update that field on the custom object that is upserted (if that's a word)

Comment: @user569925 - Just set it prior to the dml.

Comment: how do I know if I need to set it to 1 or increment that field?

Comment: @user569925 - You will need a separate DML to do it in code. I misread what you were trying to do.